# Cannot install java 64bit when 32 bit works fine

Tags: java, installation, failed-installation

I can Install Java 32 bit but not 64 bit.
I am using Fujitsu T902 running Windows 7 **64 Bit** with 4 Gigabytes of ram.
getting error code 1603

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj1hC.png)

[System Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ranVp.png)

**EDIT**: Solved - Download a complete JRE and paste it in the correct folder, then configure enviroment variables. **Thanks!**

Comment: most likely your windows 7 is 32 bits?

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of Error. So we can resolve it easily. Well try to do this, Restart your system and uninstall old versions(if any)
Disable Java content through the Java Control Panel
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download a complete JRE and paste it in the correct folder, then configure enviroment variables.

Thanks for your help though!

Comment: what is "correct folder"? I have the same issue, and the 64bit just wont install

Answer (score 1):

64bit jdk can only run on 64bit system, please make sure your windows system is 64bit. you can right click "my computer" and click property to check out

Comment: it is 64 bit Windows 7 pro

Answer (score 1):

Only explanation if you are actually using Windows 7 64 bit is if you are running a virtual machine where windows is 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

this error is java update error. Maybe you are using online installer. Download an offline JDK/JRE installer and then try.
Your system is x64 so you need to install 64 bit java.

Also please follow this link for additional information:
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml